# Why are parentheses needed on this F# function?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, let

Why are parentheses needed on `read_rest_of_csv` below?

```
    let read_rest_of_csv() =
        csv_data.Add(csv_fileH.ReadFields()) |> ignore
        not csv_fileH.EndOfData

    while read_rest_of_csv() do ignore None
```

Without the parentheses, the loop will not terminate.

```
open System
open System.Threading
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
open System.Text
open System.Threading.Tasks
open System.IO
open Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let csv_fileH = new TextFieldParser("test1.csv")
    csv_fileH.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited |> ignore
    let x = csv_fileH.SetDelimiters(",")
    let csv_data = new List<string[]>()

    let eod = csv_fileH.EndOfData
    if not eod then
        let column_headings = csv_fileH.ReadFields()
        csv_data.Add(column_headings) |> ignore

        let read_rest_of_csv =
            csv_data.Add(csv_fileH.ReadFields()) |> ignore
            not csv_fileH.EndOfData

        while read_rest_of_csv do ignore None

    0
```

I apologize that I cannot remember where I saw this. I think it was in SO. It's a nice example.

Could this be that without parens I'm dealing with a function object of sorts?

I am indeed coming from not only a C, C++, and C# background, but also an intermediate Clojure background as well. In my case with F# syntax, reading my Haskell manual in a little more detail might have helped, because the syntaxes seem similar.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It seems that people coming from C-family languages (C#, Java, C, C++, JavaScript) are having problems understanding the use of brackets in F#. I certainly had, and it took me some years learning how things work.

In a nutshell, the most basic building block in F# is a *value*. Values can be `let`-bound:

```
let foo = bar
```

This means that `foo` is a value, which happens to be equal to `bar`.

Functions are also values:

```
// 'a -> 'a * 'a
let f = fun x -> x, x
```

Here, `f` is a function that takes some value (`x`) and returns a tuple with `x` as both the first and the second element.

That's a bit cumbersome to write, so there's a shorthand for that:

```
// 'a -> 'a * 'a
let f x = x, x
```

Notice that there are no brackets in these expressions.

Sometimes you need to adjust the precedence of operators. Just like in maths, `1 + 2 * 3` (which is equivalent to `1 + (2 * 3)`) isn't the same as `(1 + 2) * 3`. In F#, you also use brackets to override precedence. Thus

```
// 'a -> string * 'a
let f x = someOtherFunction x, x
```

isn't the same as

```
// x:'a -> string
let f x = someOtherFunction (x, x)
```

(in this case, `someOtherFunction` is a function that returns a `string`.)

Notice that the brackets don't denote a function call; they're only there to control order of evaluation.

Sometimes, you want to define a function that doesn't take any input. You can't, however, define it like this:

```
let f = whatever
```

because that would make it a *value* that's immediately `let`-bound to `whatever`. Instead, you can let the function take a value of the built-in type `unit`. This type only has a single value, which is written `()`:

```
let f () = whatever
```

This means that `f` is a function that *pattern matches* its input against the only known value of `unit`.

Whenever you invoke `f` with `()`, the expression `whatever` is evaluated and returned.

Comment: You made a good point about people's programming backgrounds coming to F#. So, I added some more to the OP to indicate my background. The part I'm going to have to get used are things like unit, (), and those bindings.

Answer (score 7):

Without the parentheses, the content executes once and never again. `read_rest_of_csv` has a type of `bool`: You are basically saying `while true do ignore None`.

The parentheses indicate that `read_rest_of_csv` has type `unit -> bool`, so every time you invoke it, it reads a row and moves the cursor. Otherwise, it will only do this once.

Comment: Could I have used brackets instead of parens?

Comment: For "brackets", read "parentheses". I'll edit my answer (not down with the kids, I'm afraid).

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is that:

```
let read_rest_of_csv =
    csv_data.Add(csv_fileH.ReadFields()) |> ignore
    not csv_fileH.EndOfData
```

is not a function at all.  This is no different from:

```
> let i = 1;;

val i : int = 1
```

This declares a binding with an integer value.  If you want to declare a binding with a function value which takes no parameters, that looks like this:

```
> let i () = 1;;

val i : unit -> int
```

The exact same reasoning applies to `read_rest_of_csv`.  Without the parenthesis, you are declaring a binding with type `bool`.  With the parenthesis, you are declaring a binding with type `unit->bool` i.e. a binding with a function value where the function takes no inputs and returns a bool value.