# How to call extension methods to pass result to an F# function

Tags: linq, f#

Why in Example 1, 2, 3 I have no problem but example 3 gives me an error that says:

> This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected

```
let add a b =
    a + b

printfn "Example 1: %i" (add 1 2)

let append (list:seq<int>) x =
    list.Concat [x]

let count = (append [1;2] 3).Count()
printfn "Example 2: %i" count

printfn "Example 3: %i" (Enumerable.Count(append [1;2] 3))

printfn "Example 4: %i" (append [1;2] 3).Count
```

Comment: I suspect you need extra brackets (but don't have the compiler to check right now) - try `((append [1;2] 3).Count)`

Comment: You forgot parentheses: `(append [1;2] 3).Count()`

Comment: `Count()` is an extension method, not a property, so you need to supply `()` in order to call it. Additionally, you also need to group the entire expression in brackets: `((append [1;2] 3).Count())`. Here's an answer that explains when to use brackets, and why, in F#: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39296035/126014

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mark for the tip! The example below is what works for what I was trying to do originally.

```
let append (list:seq<int>) x =
    list.Concat [x]

printfn "Example 4: %i" ((append [1;2] 3).Count())
```

If I have a chance to briefly explain why the additional set of surrounding parenthesis are needed hear I'll update this answer with the details.